# A prime ideal $I$ in $\mathbb Z[\sqrt{-5}]$ so that $7\in I$.

Tags: abstract-algebra, galois-theory, ideals

> Find a prime ideal $I$ in $\mathbb Z[\sqrt{-5}]$ such that $7\in I$.

I claimed that $I= 7\mathbb Z[\sqrt{-5}]$, and tried to prove that if $x,y\in \mathbb Z[\sqrt{-5}]$ and so that $xy\in I$ then must $x$ or $y$ in $I$. But there will be somewhat long calculations which I don't know if it reaches me to my goal or not!

So I wonder If this the right way to prove it or not.. Or maybe $7 \mathbb Z[\sqrt{-5}]$ is not even the desired ideal!

Comment: $\mathbb{Z}[7\sqrt{-5}]$ is not an ideal (it contains 1). You probably mean $7\mathbb{Z}[\sqrt{-5}]$.

Comment: yes thank you that what i mean .. i will edit it

Answer (score 4):

Hint: $14 = 3^2 + 5 \cdot 1^2$

Comment: So how to find the ideal?

Answer (score 2):

**Hint**: By algebraic number theory, any prime ideal containing $7$ is a prime divisor of $7\Bbb Z[\sqrt{-5}]$. Perhaps you have a characterization of these prime divisors in terms of the discriminant of $\Bbb Z[\sqrt{-5}]$.

Comment: I didn't study algebraic number theory. I thought it can be solved in basic abstract algebra

Comment: It can, basically. Try to find integer solutions to $(a+b\sqrt {-5})(c+d\sqrt {-5})=7x+7y\sqrt {-5}$. That is try to solve $ac-5bd \equiv ad+bc \equiv 0 (mod$ $7)$.

Comment: @walcher: $\mathbb{Z}[\sqrt{-5}]$ is not a PID.

Comment: @Prometheus That doesn't mean that finding such a pair can't help you find a prime ideal...

Comment: @Prometheus No, but it is a Dedekind domain and a quadratic integer ring. You are right in general that this method won't work, but since the discriminant $D=-20$ is a square $mod$ $7$, the ideal $I=7\Bbb Z[\sqrt {-5}]$ splits in $\Bbb Z[\sqrt {-5}]$. So if we can find two non-associate elements, which don't lie in $I$ such that their product lies in $I$, then by the unique prime factorisation, the ideals generated by those elements must be prime.